# How can I float the third element to the left?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-float

I have four elements. I need element number 3 to float left, while the remaining elements float right.

[image: example]

### Additional Factors

- Columns are not equal width.
- Cannot use `position: absolute`, since the hight of the children is unknown and it's important for the wrapper to remain relative to the height.
- Cannot use `display: grid`, since the code needs to support IE10.
- I cannot reorder the elements in HTML. I can, however, include various wrappers around certain elements, as long as they're in order. The reason is because elements 1, 2, 3 and 4 are supposed to show up in order on mobile devices, i.e. responsive.

### What I've tried so far

- Using Float Right/Left - https://jsfiddle.net/s4542jz2/2/
- Using Float Right/None - https://jsfiddle.net/zfLspshq/2/
- Using Inline-block - https://jsfiddle.net/kq8dbn5s/2/
- Using Flexbox - https://jsfiddle.net/g3wwdw84/6/

### Update

- I've updated the question to say that I cannot reorder the HTML.

Comment: have you tried to set block formatting context? https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/12/understanding-css-layout-block-formatting-context/

Comment: Can you change the div orders in the html?

Comment: Change the source order.... 3, 1 , 2, 4...simples.

Comment: @Stickers - I cannot change the html.

Comment: Then I suspect you are out of luck....as you have found.

Comment: @Tomasz - that's a good source. I will try to see if that helps.

Comment: If height is fixed you could do this https://jsfiddle.net/g3wwdw84/16/

Comment: IE10 does support its own version of grid, it's not as nice but it might still work for your purposes: https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/11/26/should-i-try-to-use-the-ie-implementation-of-css-grid-layout/

Comment: @NenadVracar - The hight of the wrapper is relative to the children. Cannot be fixed.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See: [mcve]

Comment: Is the width of #3 fixed or can it be percentage?

Comment: you could use flex:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @Stickers - yes, the width is fixed.

Comment: @JensIngels - Please provide a flex example. I wasn't able to use flex - row, because the columns are not identical in width; and was not able to use flex - column, because I do not have a fixed height.

Comment: I assume something like this: https://fiddle.jshell.net/mqbzj12z/50/

However this will include setting a position relative to the container and using position absolute. I don't understand your problem with not been able to use it. I do have my worries regarding your IE10 support. It's not something that well supported these days. You could use a simple plain javascript solution to safe you some trouble.

Comment: @JensIngels - There are 2 issues with it. First, the columns are not different widths. Second, items have been reordered in html. See the Additional Factors paragraph in the question.

Comment: flex has an order styling. Maybe you can use that for the order. As far the second issue goes I just give them a min, max width for visual. I don't think their would be many issues with auto width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you mentioned the HTML cannot be changed because you still need the #1, #2, #3, #4 display order on mobile. But you can actually reorder them  to differ from the original markup (visually not in the DOM though). Therefore, I would suggest to use the #3, #1, #2, #4 order in the markup to make such layout possible, since you also commented #3 is fixed width. Here is the approach with just CSS float + flexbox + media queries.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6s2at2wc/)**

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid pink;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.one   { order: 1; }
.two   { order: 2; }
.three { order: 3; }
.four  { order: 4; }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: block;
  }
  .wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  .three {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
  }
  .one,
  .two,
  .four {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="three">three</div>
  <div class="one">one</div>
  <div class="two">two</div>
  <div class="four">four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a good point. I can reorder the elements on mobile view using flex order. Here's another example https://jsfiddle.net/g3wwdw84/32/

Comment: Yep, that's basically the same but floating to the other side.

Comment: I realize that this doesn't directly fix the CSS issue, but it provides a working solution. For this reason I'm marking this as the accepted answer.

Comment: You can offer a bounty and see if you still need a better solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to get the heights of the four elements and set the height of the wrapper to the height of the higher of the two columns. This solution is based on your flexbox approach. I just changed the height of element "three" a bit to demonstrate the possible different heights of the two columns:

Note: Right now the left column is higher. If you change the height of `.tree` to less than 600px  you see that the wrapper gets the height of the right column.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var heightthree = $('.three').outerHeight();
var heightone = $('.one').outerHeight();
var heighttwo = $('.two').outerHeight();
var heightfour = $('.four').outerHeight();
var heightright = heightone + heighttwo + heightfour;
  if (heightthree > heightright) {
    $('.wrapper').css('height', heightthree)
  } else {
    $('.wrapper').css('height', heightright)
  }
})
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #fa0;
}

.one {
  order: 2;
  height: 200px;
  background: #999;
  width: 55%;
}

.two {
  order: 3;
  height: 200px;
  background: #888;
  width: 55%;
}

.three {
  order: 1;
  height: 620px;
  background: black;
  width: 45%;
  color: white;
}

.four {
  order: 4;
  height: 200px;
  background: #777;
  width: 55%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">one</div>
  <div class="two">two</div>
  <div class="three">three</div>
  <div class="four">four</div>
</div>
```

And here a version where the left column is less high than the right one: https://jsfiddle.net/8m2cjb6r/21/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The wrapper height must be relative to the children.

Comment: what do you mean by relative - dynamic / determined by contents?

Comment: The wrapper cannot have a fixed hight. Its height is dependent on the children. If it could have a fixed hight, I could just use position: absolute.

Comment: can you use jQuery?

Comment: Please note: I changed my answer to a jQuery-based solution now, based on your flexbox approach.

Comment: Thank you. I would prefer a CSS solution, but perhaps this will help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you looking for?

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.one {
  height: 200px;
  background: #999;
  width: 55%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.two {
  height: 200px;
  background: #888;
  width: 55%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.three {
  float: left;
  height: 600px;
  background: black;
  width: 45%;
}

.four {
  height: 200px;
  background: #777;
  width: 55%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="three">three</div>
  <div class="one">one</div>
  <div class="two">two</div>
  <div class="four">four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm unable to modify the HTML code. The reason is that on the mobile devices, the divs are supposed to appear in order. I will update the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this :

https://jsfiddle.net/s4542jz2/13/

Split in two different div :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper_left">
        <div class="three">three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper_right">
    <div class="one">one</div>
    <div class="two">two</div>
    <div class="four">four</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm unable to modify the html. The reason is that on mobile devices, each element is supposed to appear in order, i.e. one, two, three, four.

Comment: Can you use the `position: fixed;` ?

Comment: `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` will take the element out of flow, i.e. the wrapper will not wrap around it. I explain it more in the question. If you think you can make it work, feel free to provide an example.